# Packets out of order. Expected 1 received 0. Packet size=145

Tags: php, mysql

We are receiving below error on the php7.0, laravel5.*

> Packets out of order. Expected 1 received 0. Packet size=145

But this error did not come in the php7.4, laravel 7

I have try in the job \DB::reconnect() then this issue solve. But it is hard this thing in all files.
Please suggest better solution.

Comment: Probably your mysql driver is out of date and out of support. You probably need to upgrade your php or downgrade your mysql

Comment: Usually this is because you spent too much time between 2 queries. You should refactor your code where this issue occurs. This is a serious design problem if all of your code has this issue.

Comment: Both PHP 7.0 and Laravel 5.* are out of support since years. If this is no longer happening when using Laravel 7 and PHP 7.4, be happy that you updated your application

Comment: 7.0 is from 2015. It's time to update.